# Writing DLL for C# and C++ Applications

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I need to write a couple DLLs that will both be accessed from a C# application and a C++ application.  Initially, I was thinking that I could save time/effort by writing the DLLs in C# and linking to them from the C# and C++ applications.  Is this approach wise, or should the DLLs be written using C++?

Comment: I would say the best approach would be c++

Comment: COM is the universal glue in Windows.  Very easy to do in C#, not so easy to use in a C++ app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice would be to implement the code where you are most comfortable, but don't forget the interop requirement as you go. Know upfront what your interface is and what glue is required in the end product.  Write the interface and test the interop before you fill out the implementation.

If the complexity of  your requirement makes comfort level irrelevant, I would write it in C++ in such a way that you can access via P/Invoke.

One important factor is are you using C++/CLI or native C++.  It's a lot easier to interop between C++/CLI and C#, in either direction.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to get it all working in C# first.  When I'll worry about linking the C# DLL into the C++ application.

Comment: After spending 2 days trying to link to a C# DLL, I've decided to backtrack and write my DLLs in C++.  Linking to unmanaged code seems to be a lot easier, and I'd like to finish this project with a at least a few hairs left in my head.

Comment: @Jim Fell - sorry to hear that, I hope my advice has not caused you a lot of wasted time. btw I share your follicular sparseness and sympathize with desire to reduce stress level.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you write your DLLs in C++, expose their public classes to COM using [ATL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Template_Library) or similar, then have [tlbimp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx%28VS.80%29.aspx) generate a thin C# wrapper around the COM interfaces.

Comment: @Steve, I don't know what I was thinking, thanks for the heads-up :)

Answer (score 0):

If the DLL is to be used in other .Net applications, then you are pretty safe writing it in C# or C++, whichever you are more comfortable in.

If the DLL is to be used elsewhere, you will find it easier to write it in C++.